# Conditional Branching Efficiency

Tags: performance, conditional-statements

We were a part of a discussion on how to make codes more efficient and on the topic of branching on `if-else`, this came up.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
if (a==1) {
    //... tasks
} else if (a==2) {
   //... tasks
}
...
} else if (a==9) {
    //... tasks
}
```

The discussion proved that the upper code is lesser efficient than the one below because of the number of comparisons that must be made towards the lower half of the code.

Consider this alternative:

```
if (a<=4) {
    if (a==1) {
        //... tasks
    } else if (a==2) {
        //... tasks
    }
    ...
} else {
    if (a==5) {
        //... tasks
    } else if (a==6) {
        //... tasks
    }
    ...
}
```

In the above case, checking for `a=5,6,7, or 8` takes lesser number of comparisons and is clearly more efficient. But I've never come across a code where they use this logic. Most codes usually use the `switch` statement or the normal `if` condition as mentioned in the former snippet. Is the latter code really more efficient or does it take the same amount of time?

**Edit**: The above is just an example. The general idea is to distinguish disjoint sets of conditions from a pool of conditions and then apply extra conditions based on the reason of disjoint.

Comment: Switch statements are often compiled this way for the exact reasons that you've mentioned. So there's no need to do it manually unless you have a really good reason to.

Comment: Depending on the language (or a compiler/JIT implementation), a `switch` statement will most likely actually be a table lookup, and therefore a single comparison.

Comment: @Slanec, if suppose the values being compared to are not integers and that for some reason we cannot use `switch`. Is it a good practice then to break the conditions into disjoint sets (if possible) and then apply extra conditions (like the latter)?

Comment: The 2nd code is slower if `a==1` almost always. This is why the compiler often has a hard time making these choices. The optimal code is data dependent.

Comment: @usr, True, the example is purely for the purpose of writing an example. I meant to discuss possibilities if and when there are several disjoint sets among a set of conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the second code is more efficient in the average case.

There are three reasons why you usually don't see such code:

1. The improvement is relatively slight. The amount varies depending on your CPU, but you only save a single digit count of CPU cycles.
2. The impact on code readability is severe.
3. The amount of code that needs optimization is usually less the one percent of the code that's written.

You see, for the vast majority of the code it's simply not worth it.

---

Also note that the second code may just as well be *slower* than the first one: If `a == 1` is the vast majority of cases, the second code needlessly adds a second comparison to the critical path. Never optimize without understanding your critical path.